# Can we run vba sub by clicking a cell which has a formula?

Tags: vba, excel, formula

Is it possible to run the VBA Sub by clicking a cell which has a formula in it.

I know its possible to run on a cell which doesn't have a formula to determine its value.

How to go about it?

Kindly share your thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the selection change event and test the `.HasFormula` property:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.HasFormula Then
        '// your code here
    End If
End Sub
```